# Why does this class definition result in a NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby, class, instance, nomethoderror

I've looked for a solution to this, but the most relevant answers seem to prescribe using `self.`, which I'm already doing; I'm unable to phrase my search in such a way that I can find what I'm doing wrong. I'm defining a class as below, but when I try to create an instance I get

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `valid_pegs?' for #<Code:0x00007fffc58d1608>
```

I've tried defining `valid_pegs?` as an instance method instead, which I can get to work if I call it as such, but this is a problem for a course, and I'm expected to define it as a class method.

So why doesn't it work?

```
class Code
  POSSIBLE_PEGS = {
    "R" => :red,
    "G" => :green,
    "B" => :blue,
    "Y" => :yellow
  }

  attr_reader :pegs

  def self.valid_pegs?(peg_arr)
    outcome = true
    peg_arr.each {|peg| outcome = false if !POSSIBLE_PEGS.include?(peg.upcase)}
    return outcome
  end

  def initialize(peg_arr)
    if !self.valid_pegs?(peg_arr)
      raise "Those are not all valid pegs"
    else
      @pegs = []
      peg_arr.each {|peg| @pegs << peg.upcase}
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Once you have working code I suggest you post it at SO's sister-site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There you will get useful advice on how to improve your code.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, stylistically I would change the `if !condition` to a guard clause: `raise 'foo' unless condition` followed by the two lines you have inside your `else`.

Comment: Also unrelated, you can define `Code::valid_pegs` more simply: `def self.valid_pegs?(peg_arr); peg_arr.all? { |peg| POSSIBLE_PEGS.include?(peg.upcase) }; end`. See [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F). Moreover, `all?` *short-circuits*, meaning that (if and) as soon as `POSSIBLE_PEGS.include?(peg.upcase) #=> false`, `all?` returns `false` without examining the remaining elements of `peg_arr`.

Comment: Thanks, @CarySwoveland, I was unaware of Code Review. Looks like an excellent resource.

Comment: Thanks, @anothermh, I hadn't learned about `unless`, nor had I heard the term "guard clause."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there!

```
if !self.class.valid_pegs?(peg_arr)
```

or

```
if !Code.valid_pegs?(peg_arr)
```

Defining a self.function-method(in this case, self.valid_pegs) is a "class level" or a singleton method.
While the "self" used inside the class definition is just a reference to the object.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. So, if I understand you, when I use `self.` in defining a method within a class, it is a class method, but calling it within the class requires using the class name, because in that context `self.` refers to an instance?

Comment: Also, doesn't calling the method without `self.` also refer to the instance?

Comment: Your first comment is correct!. The second one is also correct.
In your sample code, you can call initialize-method as initialize or self.initialize.
But which one should you use? It's all up to you. Though there are some suggestions about coding best practice, it's really up to you.

You can check it here: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-self-unless-required

P.S. 
You can also use self for a variable. There will be times local(define inside a method) and instance variable will have the same name. Using self on this will help with the variable ambiguity.